# Eclipse - ability to open a file from command line at a specific line number

Tags: python, eclipse, integration

I'm looking for a way to open a files from command line at a specific line number. It looks like eclipse doesn't support this functionality. Here is a four-year old ticket:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305336

My question is, what is the best way to workaround this issue. I have a program in python and I want to send a message to Eclipse to open a specific file at the specific line number. Does Eclipse have a mechanism which can help with that?

Comment: Have you tried the `--help` option and see?

Comment: Here are command line arguments http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html there is no `--help` option if you are interested.